# jquery validation plugin stops when remote

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

it seams that i have a small problem on a project of mine.

i am using jquery validation plugin on this form:

> ```
>                   <input type="text" name = "lname" placeholder="Last Name" id="lname" required/>
>                   <label for="lname" generated="true" class="error"></label>
>
>                   <input type="text" name = "email" placeholder="E-mail" id="email" class="email" required/>
>                   <label for="email" generated="true" class="error"></label>
>
>                   <input type="text" name = "username" placeholder="Username" id="username" required/>
>                   <label for="username" generated="true" class="error"></label>
>
>                   <input type="password" name = "password" placeholder="Password" id="password" required/>
>                   <label for="password" generated="true" class="error"></label>
>
>                   <input type="password" name = "cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="confirm_password" required/>
>                   <label for="cpassword" generated="true" class="error"></label>
>
>                   <input class="button" type="submit" name="regbutton" id="regbutton" value="Register" />
>               </form>
> ```

And here are the rules:

> $(document).ready(function () {
>
> $('#registration').validate({
>
> ```
>   rules: {
>           fname:{
>               minlength: 3,
>           },
>           lname: {
>               minlength: 3,
>           },
>           email: {
>               email: true,
>               remote: { url:"../php/checkemail.php", async:false >}
>           },
>           username: {
>               minlength: 4,
>               maxlength: 16,
>               remote: { url:"../php/checkusername.php", async:false }
>           },
>           password: {
>               minlength: 8,
>               maxlength: 16,
>           },
>           cpassword: {
>               equalTo: "#password",
>           },
>   },
>       messages: {
>           fname: {
>               minlength: "Your name must be at least 3 characters long.",
>           },
>           lname: {
>               minlength: "Your name must be at least 3 characters long.",
>           },
>           email: {
>               email: "Please enter a valid e-mail address.",
>               remote: "This email is already registered.",
>           },
>           username: {
>               minlength: "Your username must be at least 4 characters long but less than 16",
>               maxlength: "Your username must be at least 4 characters long but less than 16",
>               remote: "This username is already registered.",
>           },
>           password: {
>               minlength: "Your password must be at least 8 characters long but less than 16",
>               maxlength: "Your password must be at least 8 characters long but less than 16",
>           },
>           cpassword: {
>               equalTo: "The passwords do not match.",
>           },
>       },
>
>   submitHandler: function(form) { 
>       $('#registration').submit();
>       return false;
>   },
> ```
>
> });
>   });

also checkemail.php (checkusername.php is the same but obviously with username in stead of email):

> include ('dbcon.php');
>    if (isset($_POST['email']))
>
> ```
> {
>     $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
>
>     if (!empty($email)) 
>
> {
>         $email_query = mysql_query("SELECT *
>                                        FROM users
>                                        WHERE email = '$email'");
>          if($email_query)
>
>          {
>            echo "true";
>            exit;
>          }
>         else
>         {
>           echo "false";
>           exit;
>         }
> }
> ```
>
> }

I have tried every combination I found. the simple remote: "url", the one with the type and data:{function....}, etc. nothing seams to be working... same for the check PHP files, whenever I put the remote line in my validation code the form stops working when I click submit. if I remove the remote line everything works perfectly. Does anyone know what can the problem be? I'm really out of ideas and out of places to look for one.

Answer (score 0):

So,

I changed my php file to this because i think that's where my whole verification stops:

> if(isset($_POST['email']))
>
> {
>
> $email = mysqli_real_escape_string(strtolower($_POST['email']));
>
> $check= mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE LOWER email = '$email'");
>
> if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($check))
>
> {
>
> ```
>   echo "false";
> ```
>
> }else{
>
> ```
>   echo "true";
> ```
>
> }
>
> }

but still nothing... i get no message, my form doesn't submit, unless i delete the "remote: "url"" part.. than everything works great again...

Answer (score 0):

I got that part to work, the problem seamed to be the relative url's, it couldn't find the php file, so in stead of ../ i now use ./ and it works until there, but in the console it gives me 200 ok and it sends me "true" no matter if the e-mail and user are available or not and it doesn't give me any message in the form... does anyone have any idea about how to fix this?

also, if i put the data: { x: function....} and type it jumps over the entire validation and let's me submit even an empty form.